# Why Bootstrap's grid gutters in the middle are twice as large as on the edges?

Tags: page-layout, grids, layout, white-space, bootstrap

The [Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) of the popular [Bootstrap Framework](http://getbootstrap.com/) creates column grid where the gap in the middle between columns is twice as large as the edge margins:

http://jsbin.com/baxunex/edit?html,css,output

Is there any reasons for this unequal spacing (as opposed to making all gaps of equal size)?

Are there known design principles supporting this decision?

Comment: Would it be more important to ask: was there actually a decision?

Comment: @Paul I can ask it, but what is the answer? ;)

Comment: Try some CSS magic.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap adds padding left & right to its columns. Causing the double up of spacing where columns meet. In essence the spacing is of equal size. When using the parent class of `.container` (rather than .contain-fluid) the columns are centred on the page, making the left right margins unnoticeable.

The alternative is putting padding only left or right, causing the first or last column to have unusual spacing. Which could be offset with :first or :last selectors to remove the padding.

In a mobile first approach padding consistent left and right keeps the columns centred with even breathing space.

[image: Bootstrap Paddin]

EDIT: On looking at it further, the `.row` has negative margin equal to the padding size. Zero out the .row margin and it has equal spacing. As to why its like that....

Answer (score 1):

The reason for any desicion (if there even was a councious decision) is only known by the Bootstrap development team. I did have a quick search on the GitHub repo, and there are a few issues relating to the margins but nothing about any specific design decisions.

The reason for the inconsistency is that the grid columns extend to the edge of the container, and the containers margin (or padding) is smaller than the combined gutter width. I would suspect this is just an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behavior of the bootstrap's grid. When you define a column, we always specify the margin left and right. When two columns are close, they add their respective margins.

Comment: Isn't it the point of the framework to specify the margins for you as part of its grid?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: (Hence my question in your post!)  ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Columns have L/R padding of 15px for a total of 30 between them - called a gutter.  (You can turn it off on a row by adding class no-gutters).

The outside columns have no neighbor so only see one padding 15px on the outsides.

Containers also have the same padding in case you are just having a container and content- without a row of columns (I guess).

If you add a row, it assumes you will be adding columns that have padding built in, so the row effectively removes the parent container's padding area by using negative margin L/R.

Why the default is to have padding for everything is to have some built-in separation of boxes on the page.  so you can concentrate on the content 'inside' the boxes rather than the finer details of box layout.  But you can easily turn all that off with no-gutters class on the row.

Comment: You can delete this- I'm wrong

Comment: you need to delete it yourself